# How to specify authentication for Pip Project setup pip with extra-index-url in pip.ini (Windows) or pip.conf (Mac/Linux) on azure pipelines/artifacts

Tags: python, pip, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

Azure Artifacts allows posting a module to an Artifactory that can then be installed by using pip by setting extra-index-url in `pip.ini` (Windows) or `pip.conf` (Mac/Linux) 
[image]

However, when using pip install, the system is asking for a user/password
[image]

Is it possible to setup this inside `pip.conf` and / or even better use .ssh signatures?

Comment: Check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#connect-to-your-feed), there're two options. And it can be done with PAT instead of .ssh. Also, as I know it's the expected behavior when you try to connect to the feed for the first time, after that the credentials would be cached locally and you don't need to enter that again~

Comment: We have to use `artifacts keyring` package to setup and save those credentials. It's can't be done with something inside pip.conf or .ssh signatures. It requires PAT(credentials) and the artifacts keyring would keep it in local cache.

Comment: Hi, as you write, pip keyring seems to be the key for all, so thanx and accepted. Currently my keyring took my PAT but then wont log me anymore, hopefully will solve it soon :)...

Comment: It sounds like your pat doesn't work as expected, please check if you followed all the steps well in the official document. If the issue persists, consider posting a new issue with `azure-devops` tag with the details to reproduce your issue in linux to get a good assistance~

Comment: Just thinking loud, it might be worth storing the secret on the keyvault, then creating an App Entity and give it (read) access only to that particular secret, then store the keys to the Entity locally.. This makes sure that if things get compromised, overall security is intact...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, a workaround solution that worked for me. To bypass the entire process Lance Li-MSFT mentioned:

> It will ask your credentials and keep it in local cache, and it won't ask for user and password again if everything is ok

)

In the `pip.ini` / `pip.conf` file, add:

```
[global]
extra-index-url=https://<Personal Access Token>@pkgs.dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/_packaging/<Feed Name>/pypi/simple/
```

This will be useful if you are in an environment where you can't do the first interactive login (Example Use-Case: Setting up an Azure Databricks from Azure Machine Learning Workspace and installing required packages).

Comment: @ntg Please do a review of this if this works for your use case.

Comment: I am away from system access right now but will do... Thanx, this seems useful. :)

Comment: Great solution, also working for docker image builds!!

Comment: You must not store your PAT anywhere on the disk. If somebody gets access to your disk, they can retrieve the token and have access to your resources like source code, artifacts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to setup this inside pip.conf and / or even better use .ssh signatures?

What you met is **expected behavior** if it's the first time that you try to connect to the Azure Devops feed.

It will ask your credentials and keep it in local cache, and it won't ask for user and password again if everything is ok. Check my log:

[image]

**We should note:**

1. The Python Credential Provider is an `artifacts-keyring` package. It's used to keep the credentials instead of other options like `pip.conf` or `.ssh`.
2. What it asks for is a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page). For me, I enter the pat in both `User` and `Password` inputs.
3. If you still need to enter the password every time when connecting to the feed, there must be something wrong with your `Python Credential Provider`(artifacts-keyring) package. Make sure you install this package successfully before running the `pip install` command.
4. There're [two options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-packages?view=azure-devops#connect-to-your-feed) (it seems you're using option 2) to connect to the feed, they **both** need the `artifacts keyring` package to save the credentials. For me in Windows environment, it's easy to install that package. But if you're in Linux environment, you should check the step4 in Get Tools button carefully:

   [image]

Here's [the link](https://pypi.org/project/artifacts-keyring/) of prerequisites above.